# Facebook live Save Button

Tags: youtube, live-recording

We are trying to broadcast church services on multiple platforms.  Services are about 30 minutes.  We are currently doing Facebook Live, downloading the Facebook Live, and uploading that to YouTube, but if the network glitches that affects the YouTube video as well.  There is a save button on the Facebook Live interface, and on short tests this works, but for actual services it has only once actually worked.  I've tried hitting the button again. I've tried waiting for the preview to get all the way to the end and loop back to the beginning, no happy check box appears.  Is there any way to diagnose what is going on?  Is there a better setup I should use?  Currently using a mid grade phone (Moto g6), Wi-Fi connection, and Facebook app.

Comment: We're looking into OBS Studio as an alternative, but not sure that available hardware is up to the job.